# Get array of property value of each object in another array without a for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios

This might be a basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Suppose I have an NSArray (carArray) with objects of a certain type (Car).

Is it possible to get an NSArray (colorArray) with all values of a property (color) of these objects without iterating carArray with a for loop? (cfr. LINQ in .NET)

```
NSMutableArray *colorList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (Car *car in carArray)
{
    [colorList addObject:car.color];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that your object is adopting the [KVC/KVO protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html). You can get an array of the properties like:

```
NSArray *colorList = [carArray valueForKey:@"color"];
```

Actually, what `valueForKey:` method does, is to return an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using *key* on each of the array's objects. (From Apple's Documentation on NSArray)

Comment: I was looking at this method in the docs, but it wasn't very clear to me what is exactly did. I could just have tried it, of course.

Comment: Beware that using wrong key will result in a crash at runtime. This approach has no type safety so you won't be warned by the compiler for using the wrong key.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. You can do that without iterating it.

```
NSArray *colorArray = [carArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.color"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **NSSet** to get the colours:

```
NSSet *NScolors = [NSSet setWithArray:[carArray valueForKey:@"color"]];
NSArray *colors = [NScolors allObjects];
```