# Get an array of property values from an object array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

There's a class called `Employee`.

```
class Employee {

    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirth: NSDate?

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

And I have an array of `Employee` objects. What I now need is to extract the `id`s of all those objects in that array into a new array.

I also found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890330/1077789). But it's in Objective-C so it's using `valueForKeyPath` to accomplish this.

How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

You can use the `map` method, which transform an array of a certain type to an array of another type - in your case, from array of `Employee` to array of `Int`:

```
var array = [Employee]()
array.append(Employee(id: 4, firstName: "", lastName: ""))
array.append(Employee(id: 2, firstName: "", lastName: ""))

let ids = array.map { $0.id }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't want to _transform_ an `Employee` to `Int`. I simply want to extract the `id`s out of all the `Employee` objects in the array.

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9890330/1077789). But I'm using Swift types so I was wondering if there's a more Swift approach to this.

Comment: That's what the `map` does - it transforms an array of `Employee` to an array of `Int`, filled with the `id` field. Which is equivalent to saying "extract the id field from all instances of `Employee` and put them into an array"

Comment: @Isuru, this answer does exactly what you want.  It creates a new array called `ids` of all the `id` values from the array of `Employee`s.  Note, it leaves the original array intact.

Comment: Yes, sorry. A small syntax error caused me trouble earlier. My bad. Thank you. It works flawlessly.

Comment: Looks like in Swift 2 beta the correct syntax would be `array.map( { $0.id })`

Comment: if you're using an optional, make sure you ! it.  Took me hours.

Comment: @Chris forced unwrapping is usually a bad practice, because if nil it will cause the app to crash. Use it only when strictly required, and prefer optional binding (or any other "soft" unwrapping) instead

Comment: @Chris Good practice, but optional binding is still a better way to unwrap optionals.

Comment: it doesn't work in swift 2.0. I'm getting compiler error.

Comment: @Chris if you have optionals in your array then you probably want `flatmap` and just return the optional. Flat map will ignore nil values returned in the closure and not add them to the resulting array.

Comment: how can i set list of ids with map func to such custom array at once??

Answer (score 104):

Swift 5 offers many ways to get an array of property values from an array of similar objects. According to your needs, you may choose one of the **six following Playground code examples** to solve your problem.

---

### 1. Using `map` method

With Swift, types that conform to `Sequence` protocol have a [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method. The following sample code shows how to use it:

```
class Employee {
    
    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String
    
    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]

let idArray = employeeArray.map({ (employee: Employee) -> Int in
    employee.id
})
// let idArray = employeeArray.map { $0.id } // also works
print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

---

### 2. Using `for` loop

```
class Employee {
    
    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]

var idArray = [Int]()    
for employee in employeeArray {
    idArray.append(employee.id)
}
print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

---

### 3. Using `while` loop

Note that with Swift, behind the scenes, a `for` loop is just a `while` loop over a `sequence`'s iterator (see [IteratorProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol) for more details).

```
class Employee {
    
    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String
    
    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]

var idArray = [Int]()
var iterator = employeeArray.makeIterator()    
while let employee = iterator.next() {
    idArray.append(employee.id)
}
print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

---

### 4. Using a `struct` that conforms to `IteratorProtocol` and `Sequence` protocols

```
class Employee {
    
    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String
    
    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
    
}

struct EmployeeSequence: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    
    let employeeArray: [Employee]
    private var index = 0
    
    init(employeeArray: [Employee]) {
        self.employeeArray = employeeArray
    }
    
    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        guard index < employeeArray.count else { return nil }
        defer { index += 1 }
        return employeeArray[index].id
    }
    
}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]
let employeeSequence = EmployeeSequence(employeeArray: employeeArray)
let idArray = Array(employeeSequence)
print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

---

### 5. Using `Collection` protocol extension and `AnyIterator`

```
class Employee {
    
    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String
    
    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Employee {
    
    func getIDs() -> Array<Int> {
        var index = startIndex
        let iterator: AnyIterator<Int> = AnyIterator {
            defer { index = self.index(index, offsetBy: 1) }
            return index != self.endIndex ? self[index].id : nil
        }
        return Array(iterator)
    }
    
}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]

let idArray = employeeArray.getIDs()
print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

---

### 6. Using KVC and `NSArray`'s [`value(forKeyPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416468-value) method

Note that this example requires `class Employee` to inherit from `NSObject`.

```
import Foundation

class Employee: NSObject {

    @objc let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet"),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov"),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant")
]

let employeeNSArray = employeeArray as NSArray
if let idArray = employeeNSArray.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(Employee.id)) as? [Int] {
    print(idArray) // prints [1, 2, 4]
}
```

Comment: huge... That's as far as I understand complete possible approaches list

Comment: Probably could've stopped at #1 (specifically the commented out line) but nice exhaustive list!