# Quickly populate multiple arrays from SQLite pull in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to populate multiple empty arrays (up to 30) in my view controller from my SQLite DB.

My SQLite data comes out as classes with individual properties. I can get them out by looping through the instances and then appending their properties values to the empty arrays. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Otherwise I have to type out each property for each array. Also, I have multiple SQLlite tables I will pull from.

```
var Season = [String](), Sport = [String](), Team = [String](), Wins = [String]()

if let AllTeams = try DB.prepare("TeamRecords") {
   for team in allTeams { 
      if team.teamUID == 2 && team.Season > "2010-11" {
         Season.append(Team.Season)
         Sport.append(Team.Sport)
         Team.append(Team.Team)
         Wins.append(Team.Wins)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you interfacing directly with the SQLite C API or are you using some other library? You should edit your question so it follows a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - basically prepare a Playground that shows your issue and post all the text here, including what libraries you're using.

Comment: I ended up using [converting my object to an array and using map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393334/get-an-array-of-property-values-from-an-object-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: That might not be the most efficient method of obtaining your data, depending on the library or framework you are using to query SQLite.