# How to convert an array of custom objects to an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, swift

I currently have an array of custom objects

> [GenrePosters]

which is defined like so:

```
public struct GenrePosters: Decodable, Equatable{

  public let poster : String

  public init? (json: JSON) {

    guard let poster: String = "poster_path" <~~ json
      else {return nil}
    self.poster = poster
  }

  public static func ==(lhs: GenrePosters, rhs: GenrePosters) -> Bool {
    return lhs.poster == rhs.poster
  }
```

When printed to console it looks like this:

> [MyMovieGuide.GenrePosters(poster:
>   "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg"), MyMovieGuide.GenrePosters(poster:
>   "/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg"), MyMovieGuide.GenrePosters(poster:
>   "/tIKFBxBZhSXpIITiiB5Ws8VGXjt.jpg")]

I'm trying to convert the array of GenrePosters to an array of strings with only the poster values that like this:

> [
>   "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg"
>   "/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg"
>   "/tIKFBxBZhSXpIITiiB5Ws8VGXjt.jpg"]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get an array of property values from an object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393334/get-an-array-of-property-values-from-an-object-array)

Comment: I see you using the tmdb haha. Came here for a different reason, but just did a project using this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) method:

```
let posters = posterList.map {$0.poster}
```

Comment: What about `let posters = posterList.map{ $0.poster }`? Is that different than `gp in gp.poster`?

Comment: Thanks, how to convert array of strings to array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct GenrePosters: Decodable, Equatable{

    public let poster : String

    public init? (json: JSON) {

        guard let poster: String = "poster_path" <~~ json
            else {return nil}
        self.poster = poster
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: GenrePosters, rhs: GenrePosters) -> Bool {
        return lhs.poster == rhs.poster
    }
}

let genrePostersArray = [GenrePosters(poster: "one"), GenrePosters(poster: "two"), GenrePosters(poster: "three")]
let genrePostersStringArray = genrePostersArray.flatMap { $0.poster }
print(genrePostersStringArray) // ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Note that `flatMap(_:)` is unnecessary here as the result of the transform is non-optional – you can simply use `map(_:)` instead.